# Laplace transform of non-explicit function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am working with a function `p(t)` that is function of the time variable `t`. I don't have the explicit expression of `p` as function of time and I would like to apply Laplace transform to an expression that includes the function `p`. 
I started by defining all the parameters as symbolic in MATLAB

```
syms m ms k t p f;
f=(m+ms/3)*(diff(p(t),t))^2+k*(p(t))^2;
```

When I execute those lines, I get this error.

[image]

I think the problem comes from the fact that I'm trying to differentiate the function `p` with respect to `t` but I'm not sure. 
Is there a way to get the Laplace transform of the function `f`?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @Cebri Here is the error message I get                                                                 



Error using sym/subsindex (line 769)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic
variables and the body of the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric,
logical, or ':'.

Error in sym/subsref (line 814)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);

Comment: @Adriaan Done.Thanks!

Comment: @chsafouane in text please. Images are a) more difficult to read and b) we can't copy text from there, which is especially a pain when it concerns code. Otherwise: I think you are correct in your assumption that `p(t)` is the problem, as MATLAB thinks you are indexing the (unknown) function `p` with the indices in `t`. I hope someone with experience on implicit functions can help you here.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks Adriaan and I'm so sorry for the inconvenience. I'm a bit new to the website and I don't always know how to post things in the right format. I'll make sure that wouldn't happen next time^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in the definition of the parameters. In order for this code to work, a little change is necessary when it comes to defining the function "p"

```
syms m ms k t p(t) f;
f=(m+ms/3)*(diff(p(t),t))^2+k*(p(t))^2;
```

It's worth noting that the variable "t" has to be defined before p. This code defines "p" as "symfun" wich is the type given to a function when is defined using symbolic toolbox.